# Одновременная работа на github

Tags: git, github, git-push

Изучаю github возник тупик на такой ситуации. если над одной веткой работает два человека - работают одновременно, изначально командой git pull они получили файлы одинакового содержимого. После чего первый человек сделал изменения и командой git push отправил их. Второй же человек сделав свои изменения командой git push отправил их и перезаписал изменения первого, как этого избежать?

Answer (score 3):

Он не может их перезаписать. Git откажется принимать такой пуш, предложив слить обновления и смерджить их. У него есть возможность использовать ключ force или force-with-lease, чтобы перезаписать коммиты, но в этом случае с ним стоит прекратить рабочие отношения.

Comment: Мне интересен сам порядок...
Вот допустим на гите пустой файл.
Оба человека его получают командой git pull
Каждый вносит изменения в файл на компе, первый человек написав что то делает команды
git add <faliname>
git commit -a -m 'coment'
git push
После некоторого времени второй решает сохранить свои данные
какие команды ему надо писать чтобы содержимое его файла совместилось с содержимым уже измененного на гите файла?..

Comment: @ВасилийПавлов, прежде чем выполнять `git commit`, очень хорошо проделать две вещи: 1. проанализировать, не попадает ли в *commit* лишнее. 2. выполнить команду `git pull` для того, чтобы (в случае возникновения конфликта) пришлось выполнять меньше ненужной работы.

Comment: @ВасилийПавлов в общем случае достаточно git pull. Это автоматически запустит мердж файлов с разными модификациями, что не всегда является желаемым результатом, избежать этого можно, подтянув изменения с помощью git fetch.

Comment: А разве после команды git pull не сотрутся все изменения на локальном файле?

Comment: Нет, с чего бы?

Comment: Извини за назойливость.. Я чего то не догоняю прост, сейчас сделал файл на гит пустой, получил его командой git pull на двух пк, на одном изменил его, залил на гит, на втором изменил, пишу команду git pull и он полностью сливает файл с гит, удаляя локальные изменения..

Comment: Странно, такого не должно быть. У меня сейчас нет времени моделировать ситуацию, но ЕМНИП пулл открыто говорит о действиях, которые производятся, в том числе либо fast-forward, либо merge.

Comment: @ВасилийПавлов, либо вы упускаете в описании какой-то существенный момент, либо *git* настроен у вас нестандартным образом. *удаляя локальные изменения* — по умолчанию *git* должен выдать ошибку в духе `error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge. Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge. Aborting`

Answer (score 1):

попытка воспроизвести описанное в [комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/433699/#comment450262_433700) (неудачная).

создаём *bare*-репозиторий, делаем его клон в каталоге `1`:

```
$ git init --bare repo
Initialized empty Git repository in repo/
$ git clone repo 1
Cloning into '1'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
done.
```

в клоне `1` создаём пустой `file` и делаем `push` в репозиторий `repo` (здесь и далее я опускаю часть вывода команд `git ...`):

```
$ ( cd 1; touch file; git add file; git commit -m 'пустой файл'; git push )
...
```

делаем ещё два клона в каталоги `2` и `3`:

```
$ git clone repo 2
Cloning into '2'...
done.
$ git clone repo 3
Cloning into '3'...
done.
```

изменяем `file` в клоне `2` и делаем `push` в репозиторий `repo`:

```
$ ( cd 2; date > file; git add file; git commit -m '2'; git push )
...
```

наконец, проверяем, не затрутся ли наши изменения при `git pull`:

```
$ cd 3
3$ echo 123 > file
3$ git pull
remote: Counting objects: 3, done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
From repo
   61d0544..343cc48  master     -> origin/master
Updating 61d0544..343cc48
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    file
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

содержимое файла **не изменилось** содержимым из репозитория:

```
3$ cat file 
123
```